# STKAudioPlayer https soundcloud doesnot stream

Tags: ios, swift3, soundcloud

I use the below code to run a Soundcloud based URL audio file.

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<Track Name>/stream?client_id=<my Client id>

var podcastPlayer =  STKAudioPlayer.init()
podcastPlayer.delegate = self
podcastPlayer.play(urlString)
```

It does not go past the buffering state

```
func audioPlayer(_ audioPlayer: STKAudioPlayer, stateChanged state: STKAudioPlayerState, previousState: STKAudioPlayerState) {
        if( state == .playing){
            JDStatusBarNotification.dismiss()
            updateRemoteNotificationDisplay()
        }else if(state == .buffering) {
            JDStatusBarNotification.show(withStatus: "Buffering!..Please Wait!", styleName: JDStatusBarStyleRed)
            JDStatusBarNotification.showActivityIndicator(true, indicatorStyle: .gray)
        }else if(state == .stopped) {
            JDStatusBarNotification.dismiss()
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: NLConstants.NOTIF_PODCAST_UPDATE_UI), object: nil)
    }
```